Programa NASM no imprime palabras en orden alfabetico
Este programa que estoy haciendo es para poder leer un archivo de texto, contar las palabras y ordenar las palabras en orden alfabetico. Para "ahorrarme problemas" con los caracteres, decidi pasar todas las letras a minusculas.
El problema radica al ordenar alfabeticamente las palabras (almacenadas en un solo String). Si tengo en el archivo de texto "Hola como te encuentras", en lugar de darme las palabras ordenadas, da lo siguiente:
Cantidad total de palabras: 4

 a    o    e    Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Usando Gnu Debugger me di cuenta de que ocurre en
imprimir_alfabeticamente.copiar_palabra, dando lo siguiente:
0x000000000040124b in imprimir_alfabeticamente.copiar_palabra ()

Agradeceria que alguien me pueda ayudar con este problema que tengo y decirme que es lo que esta fallando.
Gracias de antemano:) . Aqui esta el codigo:
section .data
    filename        db 'archivoprueba.txt', 0
    digitos         db "0123456789ABCDEF"
    error           db "El archivo de texto sobrepasa los 2048 caracteres", 10
    lenError        equ $ - error
    numPalabras     db "Cantidad total de palabras: ", 0
    lenNumPalabras  equ $ - numPalabras

section .bss
    fileDesc    resq 1          ; Descriptor de archivo
    texto           resb 2049   ; Buffer para almacenar los datos leídos
    ;palabrasCont    resb 1600
    resultado       resb 64
    mensajeMinusculas resb 2048

section .text
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; PROCEDIMIENTOS ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
pasar_todo_minusculas:
.for_loop:  

    movzx rax, byte [rsi]      
    test rax, rax                                                                  
    jz .end_loop                                                                      

    ; Verificar si es un espacio en blanco o una nueva linea
    cmp rax, ' '                                                               
    je .guardar_espacio                                                         
    cmp rax, 10                                                                
    je .end_loop                                           


    cmp rax, 65
    jl .guardar_espacio
    cmp rax, 90
    jg .verificar_minuscula

    add rax, 32
    jmp .guardar_caracter


.verificar_minuscula:

    cmp rax, 97
    jl .guardar_espacio
    cmp rax, 122
    jg .guardar_espacio

.guardar_caracter:
    ; Verificar si el resultado esta lleno
    cmp rdi, mensajeMinusculas + 2048                                         
    jae .end_loop                                                            

    ; Almacenar el carácter modificado en el resultado
    mov [rdi], al                                                                  
    inc rdi                                                                    
    jmp .saltar_caracter                                                    

.guardar_espacio:
    ; Almacenar un espacio en blanco en el resultado
    cmp byte[rdi-1], " "
    je .post_espacio
    mov al, ' '                                                                   
    mov [rdi], al                                                             
    inc rdi                                                                  
.post_espacio:
    inc rsi                                                                    
    jmp .for_loop                                                             

.saltar_caracter:
    inc rsi                                                                  
    jmp .for_loop                                                                 

.end_loop:
    ; Almacenar un salto de linea al final del resultado
    mov al, 10                                                                   
    mov [rdi], al                                                                 
    inc rdi                                                    

    ; Calcular la longitud del resultado 
    mov rdx, rdi                                                                 
    sub rdx, mensajeMinusculas                                                            
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Imprimir mensaje ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
print:
    push rdi
    push    rax
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rax, 1
    syscall
    pop     rax
    pop rdi
    
    ret
    
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Salir del programa ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
salir:
    mov     rax, 60         
    xor     rdi, rdi        
    syscall                 
    
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Obtener contenidos ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
obtenerContenidoArchivo:

    ; Abrir el archivo
    mov     rdi, filename 
    mov     rsi, 0         
    mov     rdx, 0         
    mov     rax, 2         
    syscall            
    mov     [fileDesc], rax      

    ; Leer el archivo
    mov     rdi, [fileDesc]      
    mov     rsi, texto    
    mov     rdx, 2049      
    mov     rax, 0         
    syscall                       

    ; Cerrar el archivo
    mov     rdi, [fileDesc]      
    mov     rax, 3         
    syscall

    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Evaluar error ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
_error:
    mov rsi, error
    mov rdx, lenError
    call print
    
    jmp salir
 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Contar palabras ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
contarPalabras:
    xor r12, r12
    xor rax, rax
    mov rbx, rdi
    
.loop:
    inc r12
    cmp r12, 2048
    jge _error
    
    ;Acá se deben evaluar todos los delimitadores
    cmp byte [rdi], 0
    je .fin
    cmp byte [rdi], 10
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], ' '  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '.' 
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], ','  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '?'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '!'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], ';'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], ':'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '"'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], "'"  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '-'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '_'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '@'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '#'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '$'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '´'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '('  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], ')'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '/'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '|'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '*'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '&'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '+'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '='  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], "%"  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '^'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '¡'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '¿'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '['  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], ']'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '{'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '}'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '<'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '>'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '`'  
    je .es_delimitador
    cmp byte [rdi], '~'  
    je .es_delimitador
    jmp .siguiente_caracter

.es_delimitador:
    ; verificar si el carácter anterior era alfabético
    cmp byte [rdi-1], 'A'
    jb .siguiente_caracter  
    cmp byte [rdi-1], 'Z'
    jbe .incrementar  
    cmp byte [rdi-1], 'a'
    jb .siguiente_caracter  
    cmp byte [rdi-1], 'z'
    ja .siguiente_caracter  

.incrementar:
    inc rax  ; incrementar el contador de palabras

.siguiente_caracter:
    inc rdi  ; avanzar al siguiente carácter
    jmp .loop

.fin:
    ; verificar si el último carácter era alfabético
    cmp byte [rdi-1], 'A'
    jb .fin_final  
    cmp byte [rdi-1], 'Z'
    jbe .incrementar_final  
    cmp byte [rdi-1], 'a'
    jb .fin_final  
    cmp byte [rdi-1], 'z'
    ja .fin_final  

.incrementar_final:
    inc rax  ; incrementar el contador de palabras

.fin_final:
    ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;Imprimir Alfabeticamente;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 

imprimir_alfabeticamente:
    ;sub rsp, 2048                ; Reservar bytes en la pila

    mov rax, 97                 ; Inicializa contador de letras en 'a'
    mov rbx, rdi                

.for_palabra:
    cmp byte [rdi], 0           ; Verificar si es final del string
    je .siguiente_minus
    cmp byte [rdi], ' '         ; Verificar si es espacio
    je .imprimir_espacio
    cmp rax, 123              ; Verificar si es superior a 'z'
    jge .dejar_de_imprimir

    mov rcx, rdi                ; Puntero actual en RCX
    mov rdx, rsp                
    xor r8, r8                  ; Inicializar el contador de caracteres

.copiar_palabra:
    mov bl, byte [rcx]          ; Cargar el carácter actual
    mov byte [rdx + r8], bl     
    inc r8                      ; Incrementar el contador de caracteres
    inc rcx                     
    cmp bl, ' '                 ; Verificar si es un espacio
    jne .copiar_palabra         
    cmp bl, 0                   ; Verificar si llegamos al final del string
    je .imprimir_palabra        

    inc rdi                     
    jmp .for_palabra            

.imprimir_espacio:
    mov rsi, rsp                    
    mov rdx, r8                 
    call print                  
    mov rsi, rsp                
    mov byte [rsi], ' '         ; Agregar un espacio al final
    inc rdx                     ; Incrementar la longitud para incluir el espacio
    call print                  
    inc rdi                     ; Avanzar al siguiente carácter del string original
    jmp .for_palabra            

.imprimir_palabra:
    mov byte [rdx + r8], 0      ; Agregar el terminador nulo al final de la palabra
    mov rsi, rsp                
    mov rdx, r8                 
    call print                  
    inc rdi                     
    jmp .for_palabra            

.siguiente_minus:
    inc rax                     
    mov rdi, rbx                
    jmp .for_palabra            

.dejar_de_imprimir:
    ;add rsp, 2048                ; Restaurar la pila
    ret                         ; Regresar al llamador
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; itoa: Convierte un número entero en una cadena de dígitos
; Posicion numero 20 hay que colocarle el 0Ah
; Argumentos:
;   RCX: Dirección de la cadena de destino + 19
;   RAX; Numero entero a convertir
;   RBX: Base numerica a la cual convertir
itoa:

; Asegura que el puntero rcx apunte al inicio de la cadena de destino    
.reverse_loop:
    xor     rdx, rdx                ; rdx = 0 (para división)
    div     rbx                     ; Divide rax por rbx, guarda residuo en rbx 
    push    rbx
    mov     bl, byte[digitos + rdx] ; Convierte el residuo a carácter
    mov     byte[rcx], bl
    pop     rbx
    dec     rcx                     ; Avanza el puntero al buffer
    cmp     rax, 0                  ; Verifica si el cociente es 0
    jne     .reverse_loop           ; Si no es 0, repite el ciclo
    
    ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    global _start
_start:            
    mov     byte[resultado + 63], 10
    call    obtenerContenidoArchivo
    
    mov     rdi, texto
    
    call    contarPalabras
    
    mov     rcx, resultado
    add     rcx, 62
    mov     rbx, 10
    call    itoa
    
    ;Mensaje de numero de palabras impresas
    mov     rsi, numPalabras
    mov     rdx, lenNumPalabras
    call    print

    mov     rsi, resultado ;Esto imprime la cantidad de palabras
    mov     rdx, 64
    call    print
    ;Se pasa todo el mensaje a la variable mensajeMinusculas
    mov rsi, texto
    mov rdi, mensajeMinusculas
    
    call pasar_todo_minusculas
    
    mov rdi, mensajeMinusculas
    
    call imprimir_alfabeticamente
    
    jmp     salir


Hola Armando, Podrías decirnos que salida esperas?. Tu código produce una violación de segmento porque lees más allá del segmento de datos. Mi ejecutable debe ser ligeramente diferente ya que en la dirección del error que insicas no hay una instrucción válida. Qué instrucción produce el fallo de segmento? (puedes verlo en gdb o usando objdump)

Hola. La salida que espero al ingresar "Hola como te encuentras" es "como encuentras hola te". La instruccion en especifico no se cual es pero es el imprimir_alfabeticamente.copiar_palabra el que produce el error :/

Segment fault siempre se debe a un acceso indebido a memoria

El problema del fallo de segmentación se debe a que estás recorriendo la cadena de caracteres multiples veces y no estas actualizando adecuadamente tus punteros, de tal forma que eventualmente accedes a una posición de memoria ilegal.
Por otra parte, no he conseguido entender la lógica con la que pretendes ordenar las palabras alfabéticamente. Con el código que nos has proporcionado no consigo ver como eso puede ser posible, así que no puedo ofrecer una versión corregida.
En su lugar te diré una forma de solucionar el problema.
Básicamente, según la salida que esperas, debes construir una lista de palabras y ordenarlas. Para ello puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Modifica tu función de convertir a minúsculas para añadir \0 después de cada palabra. Cada vez que añadas un \0 para indicar el final de una palabra, almacena el índice al primer caracter de la palabra en otra zona de memoria.
Una vez que tengas una lista de índices a todas tus palabras en un array, tienes que ordenar el array según tu criterio. Eso implica escribir una función para comparar cadenas (strcmp de C).
Con todos estos elementos podrás implementar fácilmente un algoritmo de ordenación. por ejemplo el algoritmo de la burbuja debería ser secillo de implementar en ensamblador.
Una vez ordenado el array de índices simplemente imprime la lista de palabras.

En el caso de que tengas que eliminar duplicados, tendrías que hacer un paso extra. Asegúrate de que tu función strcmp devuelva 0 cuando las cadenas sean iguales de forma que la podrás utilizar para eliminar duplicados.
Para tu ejemplo sería algo como esto:
"Hola como te encuentras"
"hola\0como\0te\0encuentras"
 01234 56789 ABC DEF...       <- Indices

El array de indices sería (en hexadecimal para que se corresponda con lo números de arriba):
 [ 0 5 A D]

Luego ordenas este array usando tu strcmp y te quedaría:
 [ 5 D 0 A]

Y ya solo tienes que imprimir usando el puntero a tu buffer y el offset en el array.
Espero que esto te ayude. Si tienes dificultades en alguno de estos pasos o decides utilizar otro método no dudes en volver a preguntar.
Un saludo
